# PIL Autocontrast not supported for this image

Tags: python-imaging-library

I want to apply autoconstrast from PIL library to a .png image. With some images autoconstrast work, but with others is doesn't work

```
    raise OSError("not supported for this image mode")
```

OSError: not supported for this image mode

I give you my image, if someone can apply autocontrast on it ?

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UvKQ.png)

```
files = os.listdir('./STARE/train/images2/')
for file in files:
#inputImage = './STARE/train/images/' + file
im1 = Image.open('STARE/train/images2/' + file)
#masque = Image.open('STARE/train/GT/' + file)
image = file
image = image[:-4]
#preprocessing.N4(inputImage, './STARE/train/images/' + image + "_2.tif")
images_egal = ImageOps.autocontrast(im1)
images_egal.show()
images_egal.save('STARE/train/images_egal/' + image + "_2.png")
```

Comment: The ImageOps module contains a number of ‘ready-made’ image processing operations. This module is somewhat experimental, and most operators only work on L and RGB images. (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html) maybe your image is 32bit ? you could try:    image.convert('l')  . Not sure it will work. And in any case not sure autocontrast is better than 32bit dept

Comment: Finally I use CLAHE function of OpenCV

def CLAHE(img):
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=1.5, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    cl1 = clahe.apply(img)
    return cl1